# Does "dark matter" explain how I can have -1 apples?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

If I have 3 apples and you take 4 of them, that means I have -1 apples... is that apple made of dark matter?

Comment: I'm not sure that your questions on photons have been dealt with as thoughtfully as they might have been, but that isn't a reason to start posting satyrical questions. What will you achieve except to get downvotes and the questions closed?

Comment: No, that apple would obviously be made of antimatter.

Answer (score 1):

No that has nothing at all to do with dark matter.

The nature of dark matter is currently unknown, that does not imply that it is opposite of normal matter in any sense.

Dark matter is simply a hypothetical particle(s) that don't participate in any interactions except for gravitational interactions, or potentially, the nuclear forces.